# Join recordsets where joined value is between base value and higher base value in another row

Tags: postgresql

I want to join a recordset where a particular value in a column of the joining table falls between values over rows of the base tables. Given table b is left joined to a:

```
WITH a (v) AS (
 VALUES (1),(3),(5),(7),(9)
), b (v) AS (
 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
) SELECT a.v, b.v FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.v >= a.v /* AND ??? */
```

the target output (c) I hope to achieve is:

```
a  join  b   =   c
v        v       v
-        -      ---
1        1      1,1
3        2      1,2
5        3      3,3
7        4      3,4
9        5      5,5
                7,
                9
```

I suspect a subquery or window function might do the trick but the solution is not apparent to me and hoping there might be a few good suggestions :)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `SELECT column1 FROM ( VALUES (1),(3),(5),(7),(9) ) a` can be simplified to `VALUES (1),(3),(5),(7),(9)` inside your CTEs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
  a (v) AS (SELECT column1 FROM ( VALUES (1),(3),(5),(7),(9) ) a)
, b (v) AS (SELECT column1 FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5) ) b) 
, a2    AS (select a.v, lead(a.v) over () as v_l from a)
select a2.v,b.v from a2 left join  b on (b.v < a2.v_l and b.v >= a2.v)
```